# Как создать сайт по обмену ссылками и показами?

Tags: html

Как создать сайт по обмену ссылками и показами?

Comment: ручками товарисч, ручками...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Дети**, не используйте этот код. Он добавлен исключительно чтобы показать ПРИНЦИП действия всех таких сайтов и не претендует на полноту или безопасность.

```
<form action="exchange.php">
    <input type="text" value="http://" name="link" />
    <button type="submit">Добавить ссылку</button>
</form>
<?php
$filename = 'links.txt';
$sitename = 'http://example.com';//адрес нашего сайта
$handle = fopen($filename,'a');
fwrite($handle,$_GET['link']."\n");
fclose($handle);
$links = file($filename);
$good_links = array();
foreach ($links as $link){
    $content = file_get_contents($link);
    if(strpos($content,$sitename)!==false){
        $good_links[] = $link;
        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a><br />',$link,$link);
    }
}
file_put_contents($filename,implode("\n",$good_links));
```